# jQuery UI Append Element After The Nearest Element On Drop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the jQuery UI drop code to create a drag and drop application. At the moment I currently have it all in place and working (see here: http://screencast.com/t/Xq04huYyTU) but here's what I'm looking to achieve.

[image: So]

So what's happening here is when the dragged element reaches the content area, I want a new element called `place-element-here` to slide down and indicate to the user where they are dropping this new element onto the page.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the jQuery droppable API documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/
There are enough options and events to make that possible.

Example:
Add a new element before and/or after each of the content elements and make them "droppable". Make use of "hoverClass" for a visible droppable container effect. The "tolerance" option makes it more userfriendly if you so wish. "snap" might be also something you wanna take a look at.

Comment: Thank you so much! I shall give this a try.